# Firewall with application-level filtering in Linux?

Tags: linux, software-rec, firewall

Are there any firewalls for Linux that will allow one to **block certain ports for a specific application** while allowing other programs to use the same port, or block Internet access altogether for specific applications?

Everything based on IPTables apparently can only block ports globally for all applications.

SELinux is the only thing I've found so far that might have application-level Internet blocking capability, but it serves a broader array of security purposes and seems too complex for this task.

I don't need interactive popups like with Windows personal firewalls.  I'm OK with having to edit a config file.  This is for personal desktop Linux use, not a server.

Answer (score 1):

[RSBAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSBAC)

> Detailed control over individual user and program network accesses.

[AppArmor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apparmor)

> AppArmor allows the system administrator to associate with each program a security profile that restricts the capabilities of that program.

Comment: AppArmor can do that?  I heard about AppArmor before posting this, but didn't realize it had that capability.  I guess I need to read up on it some more.